# wp-login.php redirect problem

Tags: redirect, login

I have plugin which redirects myweb.com/wp-login.php to custom login page myweb.com/member-login/

I want to check if current page is either wp-login.php or /member-login/ but does not work. code below

```
( ( $pagenow !== 'wp-login.php') || ( $pagenow !== '/member-login/') )
```

Any clue why?

UPDATE:
In mean time a have created

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
( $pagenow !== 'wp-login.php')||( !strncmp($uri,'/member-login/',strlen('/member-login/')) )
```

and check is OK

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) to check if user is on that custom login page. So the code will be something like:

```
( ( $pagenow !== 'wp-login.php') || ( !is_page('member-login')) )
```

You can also use page id for the function.

Comment: thank you. 
check is ok, but i still have problem because WP does not detect this page.

Comment: Which plugin you're using to redirect ? Check if that plugin provides any function to check.

Comment: my own. I use this check for enable maintainance page. if my custom login is disable  then ( $pagenow !== 'wp-login.php') works I enable maintanace page for all pages except wp-login.php
But if i enable my custom login then redirects works and for some reason !is_page('member-login') is not detected by enable maintanace function.

Comment: Redirect works ok.

Comment: Remember `is_page` needs to be used when wp_query is loaded, i.e in `wp` hook, not before that like `init`

Comment: i use as 
add_action('get_header', array($this, 'maintenance'));

and i notice that 
( is_user_logged_in() && (!current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) ) 
does not work correctly